# How make query if some value is null and some are not while submitting data in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have type, `state_name`, `city_name`, `location`, `name`, `price` and `squrefeet` and I want to get result on their selection.
If I only select any one out of them or select all of them, where can I get the result of their selection?
I am taking one array and discard null value from array. But i don't know that its's true or not?

```
$state_name    = $_POST["state_name"];
$city_name     = $_POST["city_name"];
$location_name = $_POST["location_name"];
$type          = $_POST["type"];
$area_from     = $_POST["area_from"];
$area_to       = $_POST["area_to"];
$price_from    = $_POST["price_from"];
$price_to      = $_POST["price_to"];
$room          = $_POST["room"];

$a = compact('state_name', 'city_name', 'location_name');

print_r($a);

print_r(array_filter($a));die;
```

Comment: Can you give the code wherein you make a query?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this may help you:

```
if ($state_name!=null){
   $search += 'state_name,'
}if ($city_name!=null){
   $search += 'city_name,'
}
  .
  .
  .
   //do that for all of variable
 $a = compact($search);
```